# Ubuntu 18.04.1 gives error after successful install alongside Win 10

Tags: .desktop

I have a schenker laptop with win 10 on it. Initially, I couldn't install ubuntu because it always froze at language select. I added nomodeset to grub and the installation went smooth. After it was done installing. I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZhFv.jpg) message after I select ubuntu. What am I missing here ?

Comment: Those error messages can occur and the system boots normally. But if you needed `nomodeset`then probably you have a Nvidia card which means you also need to boot with `nomodeset` until you install the Nvidia drivers.